# Wacom Pen does not trigger mouse moving on Cintiq 22HD with Debian Buster

Tags: wacom

I have a Wacom Cintiq 22HD connected to my Dell Precision 7510. The screen is working fine but the pen does not trigger any mouse cursor movement. From what I understand, Debian does suppport it out of the box. The screen and pen are working fine with the same setup under Windows 10, so it is not a hardware problem.

The pen is hooked up to `/dev/input/mouse2` but does not trigger any input when moving around. The screen recognized the pen and the small LED related to pen movement is blinking when the pen touches the screen.

The following packages are installed: `libwacom-bin`, `libwacom-common`, libwacom-dev`,`libwacom2:amd64`and`xserver-xorg-input-wacom`.

The output of `xsetwacom --list` is:

```
Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus        id: 12  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad           id: 13  type: PAD       
Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser        id: 23  type: ERASER
```

There are also entries in `dmesg` related to the tablet (output of `dmesg | grep -i wacom`):

```
[    3.003718] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: WACOM
[    3.504373] input: Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/0003:056A:00FA.0001/input/input12
[    3.504409] input: Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/0003:056A:00FA.0001/input/input14
[    3.564182] wacom 0003:056A:00FA.0001: hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Tablet Cintiq 22HD Tablet] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1/input0
```

The pen is hooked up to `/dev/input/mouse2` and `/dev/input/event9` according to `cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i -A8 wacom`:

```
N: Name="Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/0003:056A:00FA.0001/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event9 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=1c1f 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000f000107
--
N: Name="Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/0003:056A:00FA.0001/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10 js0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=b
B: KEY=800 3f00c0000003ff 400 300000 0 0
B: ABS=1000000001b
```

I have tested the input with `sudo xxd /dev/input/mouse2` but there is nothing coming.

The Wacom Pen and Pad are recognized by the X session. The output of `journalctl | grep -i wacom` does not give any interesting output except maybe for the `Invalid type 'xxx' for this device` sections. But I have no idea what the output here should actually look like:

```
Apr 15 06:34:17 DAX kernel: usb 1-2: Manufacturer: WACOM
Apr 15 06:34:17 DAX kernel: input: Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/0003:056A:00FA.0001/input/input12
Apr 15 06:34:17 DAX kernel: input: Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1:1.0/0003:056A:00FA.0001/input/input14
Apr 15 06:34:17 DAX kernel: wacom 0003:056A:00FA.0001: hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Tablet Cintiq 22HD Tablet] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2.1/input0
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen (/dev/input/event9)
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) LoadModule: "wacom"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Module wacom: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) wacom: Driver for Wacom graphics tablets: PenPartner, Graphire,
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen'
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: always reports core events
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: type not specified, assuming 'stylus'.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: other types will be automatically added.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (--) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: using pressure threshold of 851 for button 1
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (--) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: maxX=95440 maxY=53860 maxZ=2047 resX=200000 resY=200000  tilt=enabled
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: hotplugging dependent devices.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: Invalid type 'pad' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: hotplugging completed.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus" (type: STYLUS, id 12)
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) acceleration profile 0
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen (/dev/input/mouse2)
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad (/dev/input/event10)
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad'
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: always reports core events
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: type not specified, assuming 'pad'.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: other types will be automatically added.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: hotplugging dependent devices.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: hotplugging completed.
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad" (type: PAD, id 13)
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad (/dev/input/js0)
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser'
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: always reports core events
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (--) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: maxX=95440 maxY=53860 maxZ=2047 resX=200000 resY=200000  tilt=enabled
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser" (type: ERASER, id 23)
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) acceleration profile 0
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Apr 15 06:34:21 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1132]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen (/dev/input/event9)
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) LoadModule: "wacom"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/wacom_drv.so
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Module wacom: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) wacom: Driver for Wacom graphics tablets: PenPartner, Graphire,
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen'
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: always reports core events
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: type not specified, assuming 'stylus'.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen: other types will be automatically added.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (--) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: using pressure threshold of 851 for button 1
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (--) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: maxX=95440 maxY=53860 maxZ=2047 resX=200000 resY=200000  tilt=enabled
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: hotplugging dependent devices.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: Invalid type 'pad' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: hotplugging completed.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus" (type: STYLUS, id 12)
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) acceleration profile 0
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen stylus: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen (/dev/input/mouse2)
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad (/dev/input/event10)
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad'
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: always reports core events
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: type not specified, assuming 'pad'.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad: other types will be automatically added.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: hotplugging dependent devices.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'stylus' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'eraser' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'cursor' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (EE) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: Invalid type 'touch' for this device.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: hotplugging completed.
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad" (type: PAD, id 13)
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad pad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pad (/dev/input/js0)
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: Applying InputClass "libinput tablet catchall"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: Applying InputClass "Wacom USB tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: Applying InputClass "Wacom tablet class"
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) Using input driver 'wacom' for 'Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser'
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: always reports core events
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (--) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: maxX=95440 maxY=53860 maxZ=2047 resX=200000 resY=200000  tilt=enabled
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser" (type: ERASER, id 23)
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) acceleration profile 0
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
Apr 15 06:34:31 DAX /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1525]: (**) Wacom Cintiq 22HD Pen eraser: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
```

I guess I have missed something obvious somewhere but I don't see anything I could try. I would be happy about any hints where to look further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more extensive research I did find two related issues in the [input-wacom](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom) Github repo, [issue 115](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/115) and [issue 140](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/140). As a workaround of the problem it is suggested  to switch off and on again the Wacom screen, and indeed this is working at least in my case. This needs to be done every time after restarting the computer. This behaviour is obviously different from Windows or macOS, but at least the screen can be used with Linux.

As a note to any person who might stumble upon this in the future: in order to make the screen working properly, you still need to map the pen correctly to the monitor, which is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082433).